# Excel JS API - SettingCollection not persisting

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm trying to update my Excel add-in to use the workbook `SettingCollection` instead of the `Office.context.document.settings` object. The documentation seems to suggest they are functionally equivalent, but with `document.settings` I can call `saveAsync()` and see my data persisted (in the PropertyBag in a webextensions.xml).

With `ctx.workbook.settings.add('key', 'value')`, I can get the settings and get them in the current session, but they don't get added to the `webextensions.xml` and aren't available on the next open of the add-in.

Is there a version of `saveAsync` for workbook settings that I'm missing? I assumed `context.sync` would take care of it, but I haven't had any luck.

Edit: I figured out what was causing my initial issue, but the problem is still there. When I close the browser tab with Excel Online and re-open it with my add-in, the settings are not persisting. Nothing is getting added to `webextensions.xml`.

Here is an example Excel.run()

```
window.Excel.run(async ctx => {
    ctx.workbook.settings.add('hello', 'world');
    await ctx.sync();
    let setting = ctx.workbook.settings.getItemOrNullObject('hello');
    setting.load('value');
    await ctx.sync();
    console.log(setting.value);
});
```

The setting 'hello' sets and exists the next if I relaunch my add-in, but not if I close the file and open my add-in.

Comment: What you are describing should work. There's no saveAsync (or any need for it) with the Excel's host-specific SettingsCollection API. Could you provide a complete Excel.run that we can use to reproduce your symptoms?

Comment: A little embarrassing because I thought I was being careful enough, but the issue ended up being a missing await on an async function that was getting the settings. My excel context was closing before `ctx.workbook.setting.getItemOrNullObject` and it wasn't doing anything, but looked like it was getting a an undefined setting.

I will close this question, but if you see this and have a minute: Where do the settings get stored using `SettingCollection` they're persisting now, but I don't see them in the xml when I download the workbook.

Comment: @RickKirkham I edited my question. I'm still not seeing anything persist in the document.

Comment: I found it by putting a zip extension on the file name: Book1.xlsx.zip. Then extract it all to a folder. Search the files in the folder for "hello".

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug with the Excel rich API for settings, can you please try the Shared API flavor as a workaround in the meantime...

function createSetting() {
    Office.context.document.settings.set("Foo", "bar");
    Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
}

function readSetting() {
    console.log(Office.context.document.settings.get("Foo"));
}