# Excel JS Online Settings not persisting past session

Tags: office-js

TL;DR: I'm having the same problem asked here: [Excel JS API - SettingCollection not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031343/excel-js-api-settingcollection-not-persisting)

Basically, I have an Excel add-in that is trying to save some information to document settings and retrieve it later. The whole thing works perfectly on the native Mac client, but does not work on Excel online. No errors, and the document setting appears to be there even after refreshing the Taskpane. But once the browser tab is refreshed, the document setting is no longer retrievable.

Is this a known problem right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a bug using the Excel-specific API. please use shared API in the meantime.

```js
function createSetting() {
    Office.context.document.settings.set("Foo", "bar");
    Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
}

function readSetting() {
    console.log(Office.context.document.settings.get("Foo"));
}
```