# Excel Online fails to persist CustomXML Parts

Tags: office-js, excel-online

I want to persist some data in CustomXMLParts using Office-js Web Addin in Excel.

This is working all right in Desktop version of Excel 2016, but does not work on Excel Online.

Here are few simple steps to reproduce this issue using ScriptLab Excel Addin.

1. Launch Script Lab
2. Run "Custom Xml Parts - Create, get, set and delete Custom XML Part" sample
3. Click on "Create XML Part" Button
4. Save and close excel (just navigate away on Excel online. Excel is autosaved on to OneDrive)
5. Open the saved document in Excel and load and run the same sample using ScriptLab
6. Click on "Change XML Part" button
7. Desktop version of Excel behaves as expected, and the persisted XMLPart content is changed. But the Online version results in error, as the setting was not persisted when workbook was saved

So is it a known bug? Is there a workaround for Excel Online? 
I came across this question on stackoverflow, but has not attracted much attention from the office-js team

[Excel JS Online Settings not persisting past session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661308/excel-js-online-settings-not-persisting-past-session)

Thanks
 - kudlur